# spring cloud consul config ignored for profile

Tags: spring, config, profile, consul

I have following entries in bootstrap.yml for my spring boot 2.0 app
If I run with profile stage4 the config values are loaded i.e. fails to start at localhost1.

Where as if I run with dev profile these values are ignored i.e consul starts with localhost instead of failing for  localhost2. any pointers?

```
spring:
   profiles: dev
   cloud:
    consul:
      host: localhost2
      port: 8500
      config:
        prefix: config
        defaultContext: myapp/dev
```

spring:
  profiles: stage
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: localhost1
      port: 8500
      config:
        prefix: config
        defaultContext: myapp/stage

Answer (score 0):

okay resolved the issue by moving stage properties to bootstrap-stage.yml